# sql select max() in subquery with multiple named tables

Tags: sql, max

This query is working:

```
SELECT * FROM essenbestellung WHERE Zaehler = (SELECT MAX(Zaehler) FROM essenbestellung WHERE Kind='0' AND Datum='02.08.2021');
```

gives the result:

```
Kind Datum         Zaehler
0    02.08.2021    1
```

But I want to combine multiple tables so I have to name them, eg `e1`. I wonder why this query is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM essenbestellung e1 WHERE e1.Zaehler=(SELECT MAX(e1.Zaehler) FROM essenbestellung WHERE e1.Kind='0' AND e1.Datum='02.08.2021');
```

gives two results:

```
Kind    Datum       Zaehler 
0       02.08.2021  0
0       02.08.2021  1
```

If I change the query to

```
e1.Zaehler=(SELECT MAX(e1.Zaehler) FROM e1...
```

I get the error

```
table 'database.e1' doesn't exist
```

How can I get that working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your subquery is referring to the alias in the *outer* query.  Give all the tables aliases and use them appropriately:

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM essenbestellung e1
WHERE e1.Zaehler = (SELECT MAX(e2.Zaehler)
                    FROM essenbestellung e2
                    WHERE e2.Kind = '0' AND e2.Datum = '02.08.2021'
                   );
```

Note that the filtering in the subquery is only on the table in the subquery in this version.